# How to get json child value of array key pair in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON variable:

```
var jsonObj= { "ClassA": { "A": "111", "B": "222", "C": "333", "D": "444", "E": "555", "F": "666", "G": "777" }, "ClassB": { "A":"22","B":"33","C":"44","D":"55","E":"66","F":"77","G":"AAA" }};
```

How do I get the *class A* value for *key A* ?

I am writing a function to allow for me to get these, something like:

```
function getDisplayValue(turnOverBracketCategory, classTypeAorB) {
    if(classTypeAorB == "A") {
        alert("1");
        return jsonObj.ClassA[turnOverBracketCategory];
    } else {
        alert("3");
        return jsonObj["ClassB"].key[turnOverBracketCategory];
    }
}
```

Where *turnOverBracketCategory* is the key ("A", "B", etc.) and the classTypeAorB defines if using "ClassA" or "ClassB".

Comment: How about just jsonObj['Class'+classTypeAorB][turnOverBracketCategory], then no need for the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can access ClassA + A doing this:

```
    jsonObj.ClassA.A
```

will return 111

You can get the keys like this

```
    Object.keys( jsonObj.ClassA );
```

will return "A","B"....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Not exactly what I wanted, but good to know that I can also access the key. Althouh, what I am looking for is the value...

I already had the answer, the issue was that the variable was not being correctly populated.

Cheers.

To get the value I would do the following

```
jsonObj.ClassA[turnOverBracketCategory]
```

or

```
jsonObj.ClassA["A"]
```